# Which hero has this costume (yellow lightning with blue and purple circle)?

Tags: character-identification, super-hero, costume

I need to know which hero has a costume like this: yellow top with a logo of a lightning above a blue and purple circle on the chest; red pants (or underwear, I don't know exactly, I saw it from a puppet).

I think the puppet was supposed to be female.

Comment: When you say the lightnimng bolt is above the circle, do you mean higher than the circle or across the circle?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a character from the [Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_%28comics%29) comics.

It sounds most similar to [Reverse-Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse-Flash) or [Eobard Thawne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eobard_Thawne):

[image: Reverse-Flash]

(Image from [dccomics.com](https://www.dc.com/characters/reverse-flash))

> Reverse-Flash is a name which has been used by several fictional supervillains in American comic books published by DC Comics. Each iteration is an enemy of the hero known as The Flash.

Check out [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=reverse%20flash&source=lnms&tbm=isch) for a ton of results that look like what you're describing.

It could also be [Kid Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kid_Flash):

[image: Kid Flash]

(Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kid_Flash))

> Kid Flash is the name of several fictional characters appearing in comic books published by DC Comics, originally created by John Broome and Carmine Infantino, as a junior counterpart to DC Comics superhero The Flash.

Again, I'd check out [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=kid%20flash&source=lnms&tbm=isch) to see if it matches what you saw.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure. It seems like a female super hero.

Comment: @GabrielVieira In that case it might be [Jesse Quick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_Chambers)?

Comment: I think we may be making an assumption that it's a speedster of some sort, but searches on lightning-themed characters hasn't turned up anything either.

Answer (score 5):

Initially that sounded like [Liberty Belle](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Liberty_Belle), albeit with reversed colours. Jesse Quick later took up the same costume.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A few more speedsters:

1. **Avery Ho**, the Flash of China: female speedster, with a purple costume and a lightning symbol

[image]

2. **Baroness Blitzkrieg**: female speedster, yellow top with lightning over a purple symbol. I guess the OP would have remembered the nazi theme of the character but, since it is for a toy, maybe the maker removed that component of the design?

[image]

3. **Iris West II**: female speedster, with yellow top and lightning. The first picture has red pants, but it seems to be a fan-art.

[image]

[image]

4. **Kid Flash**: red pants, yellow top with lightning. But male.

[image]

*Source*: I found most of these speedsters in that [article](https://www.cbr.com/dc-speedsters-ranked/).